# Why does this bitwise operation return 30 instead of 384?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, dev-c++

I am using Dev-C++ compiler. This program is supposed to print `30` but its printing `384`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int ans;

    ans = n<<3 + n<<1;
    printf("%d", ans);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Does anyone know whether Dev-C++ offers a pure C mode? If not, the C tag should probably be changed to C++.

Comment: Dev C++ is just an (outdated) IDE around an old version Mingw/GCC/G++. If I remember correctly, it picked the language based on file extension .c or .cpp.

Comment: @user3745158 Please note that `int` is a signed type and it doesn't make any sense to perform shift operations on signed types. You should switch it to `uint32_t` or similar.

Comment: @Lundin why wouldn't it make sense? As long as you know what the output is going to be it seems fine for me. And performing two shifts  by less than 4 on a integer smaller than 10 is highly unproblematic I'd say.

Comment: @Theolodis Because using a signed integer type when you want an unsigned doesn't make any sense. Using `int` sends out the message "I don't really know what I'm doing". You do _not_ want the signed type, because right shifts on negative values leads to impl. defined behavior, and left shifts on negative values leads to undefined behavior. Furthermore, if you use signed types in expressions, you might get other types that you thought were unsigned promoted into signed types, by the integer promotion rules. Furthermore, any code relying of the bit representation of signedness is non-portable.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the `+` operator has higher precedence than the `<<` operator.  What you wrote actually means:

```
ans = n << (3 + n) << 1;
```

What you actually want is:

```
ans = (n<<3) + (n<<1);
```